# I cant figure out this space key and attack animation

Tags: python, class, object, pygame, blit

I decided to add the attack images into the walking ones to see what happened and I got them to load up.

I have been attempting to break it down and piece it back together to try and find what I have been doing wrong and it may be an issue of my experience.

I have butchered my code trying to figure this out after someone gave me an explanation about my classes. I thought maybe I should try and set it up as global, and then I realize there's something I'm not doing right. I don't want someone to just write the code for me I should mention. But an explanation for why I am screwing up would be nice.

Some tutorials are helping me but not as much as when someone tells me where specifically where I went wrong. I think I made more progress there.

```
##a simple punch without the whole animation atm
class attacks(object):                  
    attack = pygame.image.load("atk3.png")
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, attack):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.attackCount = 0


    def draw(self, win):
        ## is it my redraw method?
        if (self.attack):
            if self.attackCount + 1 >= 9:
                win.blit(attack, self.attackCount//3(self.x, self.y))
                self.attackCount += 1
```

So with the class set up here im sure that something is wrong, ive been diving through forums and I know something is not right. I dont know what though.

```
def redrawGameWindow():
    global walkCount
    global attackCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    if walkCount +1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0

    bob.draw(win)
    jerk.draw(win)
    for attack in attacks:
        attack.draw(win)



    pygame.display.update()


    #While true
    #This calls the classes created
    bob = player(100, 200, 128, 128)
    jerk = enemy(500, 200, 164, 100, 600)
    attacks = []
    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False


        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        #attempting to make this into a bool that changes the value
        if  not(bob.attacking):
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                bob.attacking = True

                bob.standing = False
                bob.left = False
                bob.right = False

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and bob.x > bob.vel:
            bob.x -= bob.vel
            bob.left = True
            bob.right = False
            bob.standing = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and bob.x < 800 - bob.width - bob.vel:
            bob.x += bob.vel
            bob.right = True
            bob.left = False
            bob.standing = False
        else:
            bob.standing = True
            bob.walkCount = 0

        if not(bob.isJump):
            if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                bob.isJump = True
                bob.right = False
                bob.left = False
                bob.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if bob.jumpCount >= -10:
                neg = 1
                if bob.jumpCount < 0:
                    neg = -1
                bob.y -= (bob.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                bob.jumpCount -= 1
            else:
                bob.isJump = False
                bob.jumpCount = 10

        redrawGameWindow()

    pygame.quit()
```

Im almost sure my True loop has nothing to do with it now since im able to run walk and jump. And when I press space it loads a frame thats not an attack one so i know for sure something is happening when I hit space

Comment: Ok im not sure what to do with these comments and I hope someone can help me.  Im not sure what I dont get. I just know the issue lies within these lines that are giving me the "AttributeError: list object has no attribute draw" and the other issue I get when I change the attack to attacks is: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'attack' reference before assignment.

Comment: class attacks(object):                  
    attack = pygame.image.load("atk3.png")
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.attackCount = 0

Comment: def draw(self, win):
        self.attacks()
        if (self.attack):
            if self.attackCount + 1 >= 9:
                win.blit(attack[0], [self.attackCount//3],(self.x, self.y))
                self.attackCount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(char[0], [self.attackCount//3] (self.x ,self.y))
                self.attackCount += 1

Comment: Please read the [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page and edit your code to make it runnable.

Comment: There are a few errors I see in the 'attack' class

Comment: ussally python would give you an error message and say where the problem is. you have an atribute error so your problem is that you have put a varible in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

one of the errors I have found is that you are telling pygame to load multiple images however, you have only loaded one

```
class attacks(object):                  
    attack = pygame.image.load("atk3.png")#< ----- you are only loading one
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, attack):
        #[...]
```

and you are telling it to go in a cycle to blit different images in a group

```
    def draw(self, win):
        ## is it my redraw method?
        if (self.attack):
            if self.attackCount + 1 >= 9:
                win.blit(attack, self.attackCount//3(self.x, self.y))# you only have one image yet you are trying to blit multiple
                self.attackCount += 1
```

another error is your attack varible. to know when  you luanch an attack you do it like this

```
class attacks(object):                  
    attack = pygame.image.load("atk3.png")
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height,#attack <----- this attack shoudnt be here):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.attackCount = 0
        self.punchisluacnhed = false



    def draw(self, win):
        if (self.punchisluacnhed):
            if self.attackCount + 1 >= 9:
                win.blit(self.attack, self.attackCount//3(self.x, self.y))
                self.attackCount += 1
                #B.T.W the attack image in the draw function should have self before it since you called it in a class not in the initilization i.e import pygame etc
```

If you want the character to punch when a button is pressed you would put it in a function like this

```
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    bob.punchisluacnhed = True
    bob.standing = False
    bob.left = False
    bob.right = False
```

to tell it to stop you put an else stateent an  set every thing to false except from the standing value